# Gradle Java Plugin gives compilation error but same code in eclipse works fine

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm facing weird issue with Gradle 4.1, JDK 1.8.291 and Eclipse IDE. I created demo class to explain my problem. Please note that i set the same JDK in eclipse build Path as well.

Below code absolutely works fine in eclipse with same JDK:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> myMap=new HashMap<>();
        Long l=(myMap.get("abc")!=null)?myMap.get("abc"):0;
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

But when i'm trying to build the same code with Gradle 4.1 and same JDK which i set in ENV variable, causes compilation error:

```
> Task :compileJava
Sample.java:9: error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
                Long l=(myMap.get("abc")!=null)?myMap.get("abc"):0;
                                                                 ^
    int cannot be converted to Long
1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Below is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets { 
  main { 
    java { srcDirs = [ 'src/main' ] } 
  }
  test { 
    java { srcDirs = [ 'test' ] } 
  }
}
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening.

If i change below line like this:

```
Long l=(myMap.get("abc")!=null)?myMap.get("abc"):0L;
```

gradle build is fine. But i want to know why earlier code is failing with Gradle but success in eclipse.

Because we are migrating to Gradle 4.1 & JDK8 from older gradle version 1.9 and JDK7. I've found similar lines in various modules and all are failed due to this error. So i want to know the root cause for this issue.

Comment: I did not work for a long time with Eclipse so take this with a grain of salt: As far as I remember, uses Eclipse a different Java compiler, not the one from the JDK.

Comment: @Henry You can configure JDK and set it as default.